# Can the power of spells, charms, curses, jinxes, and hexes be contained in a potion?

Tags: harry-potter

Can the power of spells, charms, curses, jinxes, and hexes be contained in a potion? For example, can you cast a charm on a potion to make the potion have the attributes of the said charm?

If so, can you mix a potion with the Killing Curse to kill?

Comment: Interesting question! Just wondering, though. There are enough potions that could kill on their own. Why would someone try to mix a potion with the Killing Curse rather than just use a potion meant to kill? I mean, it's still a good question, though. If it's possible, mixing spells with potions could create potions with abilities that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Comment: Is there anything at all that makes you think this is possible?  I mean, beyond the question, I think it'd just be more practical, and quicker, to brew a poison to kill someone rather than some never-seen blank slate potion, so I'm not even understanding why that'd even be a theory.

Comment: It's been said (I think by JK) that the art of Potion-Making requires a wand in order to perform spells that finalise the potion and its effects. You could very easily create a potion that kills people, but you wouldn't necessarily use the "Killing Curse" in order to achieve that. If you wanted to create a potion that straight up kills somebody with no trace by using the "Killing Curse" as the magic component, you could probably do that, but the ingredients required to pull it off would have to be strong.

Comment: You'd also have to experiment to get the mixture just right, which would involve great danger to the you, especially since you'd be working with the Killing Curse of all things. There's a fair chance that your potion would just straight up kill you while you're trying to brew it if you're not careful.

Comment: What would be the point? Surely you can just make poison: "*Everyone gather 'round," said Snape, his black eyes glittering, and watch what happens to Longbottom's toad. If he has managed to produce a Shrinking Solution, it will shrink to a tadpole. If, as I don't doubt, he has done it wrong, his toad is likely to be poisoned.*" (Prisoner of Azkaban)

Comment: It looks like potion making in Harry Potter is not "placing spells in a container", as in other worlds, it is a separate art. If there is a canon proof of that, that would be an answer.

Comment: There's probably a lot of overlap between spells, potions and charms. Which one you use would depend on the situation and the knowledge/preference of the witch. At a guess I imagine spells are faster (no prep time), potions last longer and charms can be used on inanimate objects.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing is never mentioned. A "Potion of Absorbance" that will take on qualities of any spells cast at it would be a potent potion indeed, and a good idea for worldbuilding in a fan-fiction story, but at any rate that is clearly not how *most* potions work. Potions achieve effects that are often different from the closest spells (there is no "Polyjuice Spell") and cannot be counteracted the same way (so it's clearly two different magical effects, not two ways to get the same results). They gain their magical capabilities from the way they are brewed and the ingredients put in them, and a given set of ingredient brewed a certain way will always get you the same results.